# How to get %userprofile%\My Documents\

Tags: javascript

The following function will work if \My Documents\ is omitted, but I need to get to my documents.

```
OpenTextFile("test.txt");

function OpenTextFile(file) {
    var ObjShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
    var wShell   = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path     = wShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\My Documents\");
    ObjShell.ShellExecute("Notepad.exe", file, path, "Open", "1");
}
```

as is, it gives me an error: Unterminated string constant Line 7 Char 80

Comment: Is the backslash escaping the quote at `("%userprofile%\My Documents\")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a String, `\` is the escape character.  If you want to include a `\` you have to escape it.

```
wShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\\My Documents\\");
```

Answer (score 3):

You must remember to escape the `\` - like this:

```
"%userprofile%\\My Documents\\"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OpenTextFile("test.txt");

function OpenTextFile(file) {
    var ObjShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
    var wShell   = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path     = wShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\\My Documents\\");
    ObjShell.ShellExecute("Notepad.exe", file, path, "Open", "1");
}
```

Comment: You have to escape both slashes.